# Commiting external dependencies with Git

Tags: git, jar, repository, git-commit, external-dependencies

I have tried to added external lib to myProject/libs/externalLib.jar or myProject/src/main/resources/libs/externalLib.jar folders but I can't commit them to repository.

What's the best way to manage external dependencies - jar libs? How to commit them to Git repository?

Comment: Why you can't commit them to the repository? Do you have any error?

Comment: No, I haven't any error. I have added all files to index and committed but didn't see it in remote rep.

Comment: Did you push to the remote rep?

Comment: Yes, it pushed everything except jar.

Comment: And that's why you don't see it in the remote rep. If you push that commit too, you will see it in the remote rep

Comment: It worked after removing .jar from .gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to manage external JAR dependencies is to *not* version them using Git.  Instead, each developer on your team should use a local set of JAR depedencies when building.  To give an example, if you were using Maven to manage your build, then you would commit your `pom.xml` file to Git.  Then, when you add or remove a depedency you would push `pom.xml` to the repository.  Every other developer would then learn about this new depedency by pulling a single small file.

Comment: It would be great to download source from Git rep and to use it without additional configuration.

Comment: Yes, it is great to download _source_, but not JAR dependencies.  JARs already have a very nice place where they like to exist, such as the Maven Central Repository.